# How can Enter key create new lines under CKEditor 5?

Tags: ckeditor5, angular13

I add editor to my angular project using CKEditor 5.By default , Enter+shift create new line .I  would like to use only Enter key .I try to add event listner and concat 
 to content editor .
New lines were created but cursor did not flow content .So, it was not a good solution .
Any ideas ?